# How to standardise / normalise scores for multiple graders and criteria in student paper assessment

Tags: normal-distribution, average, standard-deviation, means, mean-square-error

I am grading 10 student projects with three other assessors, and the top two students will win a prize so it's important that we try and account for any grader that is overly kind or harsh in their scores.

Each project is graded (marks out of 5) by two assessors (at random from the four assessors overall) and is scored on three criteria with equal importance (originality, method, presentation). Each three grades from an assessor is averaged to produce an average score (out of five); and then the two average scores for each student project are again averaged to a final average mark out of five.

The results look like this, where the green/blue/orange/red are the four assessors.

[image]

You can see the total average score in the purple column.

But you can also see that according to "How_good_actually?" (**n.b. see edit note about this column at the bottom of this post**) we have a problem... John should have been the best project, but because he was given the red grader he has dropped out of the top two, because the red grader is very harsh. Also, Chris has managed to get into the top two for a prize despite being an average student because he got the green grader, the kindest. What's more, Joe should have been in with a shout for the other top-two position, but the red grader also knocked him down.

You can see from the next table, that the red grader has been consistently mean across the board and the green grader has been overly generous. The blue and orange graders were about right, giving roughly as many marks as they should have done.

[image]

So, my question is, how can we apply some sort of normalisation to each assessors average scores, so that according to the overall population/assessors their average scores are adjusted up/down according to how generous/harsh they have been?

The data for the main table is here:

```
ID  Student_name    How_good_actually?  Average_score_total Assessor_1_average  Assessor_1_criteria_1   Assessor_1_criteria_2   Assessor_1_criteria_3   Assessor_2_average  Assessor_2_criteria_1   Assessor_2_criteria_2   Assessor_2_criteria_3
2   Jane    4   4.33    5   5   5   5   3.67    4   3   4
5   Chris   3   3.83    4   4   5   3   3.67    4   3   4
1   John    5   3.67    4   4   3   5   3.33    4   3   3
3   Joe 4   3.67    4.67    5   4   5   2.67    3   2   3
4   Sarah   3   2.83    3.33    4   3   3   2.33    2   2   3
7   Ray 3   2.83    4   4   4   4   3   3   2   4
6   Mary    3   2.83    2.67    2   3   3   1.67    2   1   2
8   Sandra  2   2.33    2.33    2   3   2   2.33    2   2   3
9   Paul    2   2.33    3   3   3   3   1.67    1   2   2
10  Rebecca 1   1.17    1.33    1   2   1   1   1   1   1
```

Finally, sorry if I've tagged this wrong but I've tried to pick some relevant tags for the question as best I can. Not being a mathematician makes this hard as I have no idea what the best answer will be. I thought that perhaps z-scores would be appropriate but couldn't find the tag.

EDIT NOTE:

Regarding the comment from @Paul -- I have added the "How good actually" column only to illustrate that the red was harsh and the green overly good. But there would of course not be such a "how good actually"; so perhaps it was unhelpful to add this column. Nevertheless, it remains the case that green used more marks overall than the average assessors and red used less overall. So my question is really to learn how to normalise these two assessors to fit the pack better. If that makes sense?

Comment: You seem to believe "How good actually" is the best indicator and want to fit some numbers to support that? If you then go "look, my numbers support that!" then your registrar's office will be happy (probably) but you have not, in any sense, supported an objective ranking. The problem is that your marking schemes were not tightly enough defined in the first place, leading to divergence of marking with different assessors.

Comment: Hi @Paul I appreciate the comment but really just put "How good actually" to illustrate that the red was harsh and the green overly good. There would of course not be such a "how good actually"; but it remains the case that green used more marks than the average assessors and red used less. So my question is really to learn how to normalise these two assessors to fit the pack better. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also @Paul - there would of course be a keen and well defined criteria guide to the assessment task. But nevertheless, assume this was the outcome and despite all good intentions and communication we still have a couple of assessors that have deviated up/down. The question is therefore just about math, and normalisation, not about whether the assessors were briefed properly... though obviously that is very important! :)

Comment: I think you can use the standard score (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score#Calculation) (for each $x$ in scores, subtract the mean and divide the std. deviation (with $n$ as denominator)) for each assessor and for each criteria, then just *add* the criteria std. scores to get the total.

Comment: However, this hinges on 2 *statistical* assumptions: (1) each assessor scores per criteria follows normal distribution, and (2) the collections are considered as *populations*, which means for example that Grader 4 "objectively" grades lower on average than say Grader 2 (because your data show it).